# Stiffness of cloth jacket

Tags: cloth-simulation

I got a Jacket without material-volume (zero thickness) in relaxed position(sleeve-opening at trouser-waistband).

I use Physic's Cloth-Modifier with preset Cotton. Self-collision is activated.

I think i understand what Structural(stiffness) and Bending(stiffness) means.

But i actually have a jiggling shirt without stiffness.

Now the questions:

1. Does the material needs a volume?
2. What is the relation to the values (does the object's size modifys the animation)?
3. Structural and Bending are set to above 2000, why bake the animation an scrunched implusion? 
   EDIT: add question 3 screenshot [image]

Comment: try and turn off collision and see if the same implosion happens

Comment: Yes! The self-collision does the implosion. But i need self-collision. I will play with the values.

Comment: Do you have the correct verts assigned in the pinning group? What modifiers are you using? Any force fields? collision objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. By material, I assume you mean the mesh. For the purpose of simulating the cloth, the answer is no you don't need volume/thickness.

   You can dynamically add thickness that is not calculated in the simulation by adding a [*Solidify modifier*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Solidify) after the cloth modifier. This may be useful if you want the cloth mesh to appear thicker without slowing down the simulation
2. AFAIK, no. I have seen no visible differences after running a few tests.
3. I'm not sure what you mean. Could you try and explain more/add screenshots?

   From the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Physics/Cloth#Material):

   > *Structural*
   >   Overall stiffness of the cloth.
   >
   > *Bending*
   >   Wrinkle coefficient. Higher creates more large folds.

Also see the [wiki page on cloth simulation](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Physics/Cloth#Cloth_Simulation).

Comment: I have added a screenshot.

Comment: @PeterRader I'm not sure what's going on, I wasn't able to reproduce it.. Is it possible you could upload a blendfile?

Comment: Nope sorry, copyright/restricted content.